# How to use while loop in R to generate a matrix with specific number?(for->while)

Tags: while-loop

I have generated a matrix by using the following for loop.
And now I am trying to generate a same matrix using while loop but don't know how to do so.
Can anyone help with this? Thank you so much.

```
a<-matrix(0, ncol=9, nrow=9)

for(i in 1:9) {
 for(j in 1:9) {
     a[i,j]<-i*j
 }
 }


a
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
 [2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18
 [3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27
 [4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36
 [5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45
 [6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54
 [7,]    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63
 [8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72
 [9,]    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81
```

Answer (score 0):

> i<-1
>   j<-1
>   a<-matrix(0, ncol=9, nrow=9)
>   while (i<=9) {
>   +     while (j<=9) {
>   +         a[i,j]<-I*j
>   +         j<-j+1
>   +     }
>   +     i<-i+1
>   +     j<-1
>   + }